# How to fix message not shown in email activation

Tags: php, phpmailer

I can't seem to get my email activation message to be sent in my new host called infinity-free.

I tried to use phpmailer as well as the mail function but can't see my html content.

```
$to = $email;

//sender
$from = 'pianocourse101@hotmail.com';
$fromName = 'PianoCourse101';

//email subject
$subject = 'Activate your Primer Level Membership Plan!';

//attachment file path
$file = "codexworld.pdf";

//email body content
$htmlContent = "<h1>Activate your Primer Level Membership Plan!</h1>
                                                                              <p>Dear $first $last, <br />Thank you for registering your Primer Level Membership Plan with PianoCourse101! You are receiving this e-mail because you or someone else claiming to be you has selected a Primer Level Membership Plan \n\nIf you believe that this is a mistake, please send us a ticket with the subject \"How to cancel my Primer Level Membership Plan?\" and allow at least 48 hours before receiving a reply.\n\nHowever, if this is correct, then you must activate your Primer Level Membership Plan by clicking on the link below: \n\n <a href=https://www.pianocourse101.com/activate.php?email=".htmlspecialchars($to)."&activatetoken=".htmlspecialchars($token4).">Click here to activate your Primer Level Membership Plan.</a>\n\nAlternatively, you can use the following token to manually activate your Level 3 Yearly Membership Plan by clicking on the 'Activate Membership\s Section:' \n\nToken:.$token4;
                                                                          </p>";

//header for sender info
$headers = "From: $fromName"." <".$from.">";

//boundary 
$semi_rand = md5(time());
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

//headers for attachment 
$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

//multipart boundary 
$message = "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n" .
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $htmlContent . "\n\n";

//preparing attachment
if(!empty($file) > 0){
    if(is_file($file)){
        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
        $fp =    @fopen($file,"rb");
        $data =  @fread($fp,filesize($file));

        @fclose($fp);
        $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
        $message .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".basename($file)."\"\n" .
            "Content-Description: ".basename($file)."\n" .
            "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"".basename($file)."\"; size=".filesize($file).";\n" .
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
    }
}
$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}--";
$returnpath = "-f" . $from;

//send email
$mail = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $returnpath);

//email sending status
echo $mail?"<h1>Mail sent.</h1>":"<h1>Mail sending failed.</h1

>";
```

I have also used phpmailer with similar contents but can't seem to get it send through....

Comment: Do you receive an email at all? Or is it just a blank email?

Comment: If it doesn't send at all, use PHPMailer with debugging mode on and you should see what it complains about. Also check if your hosting company have any specific rules regarding sending emails. For example: GoDaddy have closed the common SMTP-ports and requires you to send all emails through their gateway.

Comment: You're asking about PHPMailer, but posted code that doesn't use it?! When you send with `mail()`, it sends through your local mail server, so check your mail server's logs. Using a MIME type of `application/octet-stream` for a PDF file isn't going to help your attachments get handled correctly.

Comment: I am using mail function but I also tried using the phpmailer with similar result and that my messages aren't showing. I am trying to contact the infinity-net to see if I can get some assistance there. Perhaps it is their issue because I got it to work before when I was with another webhost called viewen....

Comment: You are marking Your html content 7-bit. It it really 7-bit? Try to convert by `mb_convert_encoding($str, "UTF-7");`

Comment: And it is possible, that Your `$header` line contains a `\n` to much in front of `MIME`.

Comment: This is confusing as well because I thought there should be a section where I have to create a new file to write to but can't find that line in my code... I also found out that the mail has been saved as a text file successfully and sent through but the main message is not shown though

Comment: I got it working now but is there a way to save a text file using phpmailer? I used to use a fopen command with mail function